# Simple HTML DOM getting href and anchor text from within heading

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

For starters this is the code that I have

```
    <?php
    include ('parser_class.php');
        $source = file_get_html('http://www.billboard.com/search/site/awards?f[0]=ss_bb_type%3Aarticle');
        $title = $source->find('h3.title'); //getting song title
    ?>
    <div id="awar">
    <?php
        if ($title){
            $title = array_slice($title, 0, 10);
            foreach($title as $titles){
                $links = $titles->href;
                $string = $titles->innertext;
                //$string = (strlen($string) > 75) ? substr($string,0,72).'...' : $string;
    ?>
            <center>
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"><span class="song"><?php echo $string ?></span></td><td style="width: 25%; text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"><a href="http://www.billboard.com<?php echo $links ?>" class="download">Read Article</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </center>
            <hr class="betw" />

    <?php
            }
        }
        else{
            echo"<p class='song'>No Articles Found</p>";
        }
    ?>
```

Since the website has no classes on their links I am having to pull my information from something like this

`<h3 class="title">
        <a href="/articles/columns/country/6784891/lady-antebellum-charles-kelley-steps-out-on-his-own">Lady Antebellum's Charles Kelley Steps Out On His Own In New York City</a>
</h3>`

Calling for `innertext` I get everything within the `h3`

What I need is to figure out how to get the `href` and the `anchor text` separately from within the `h3`

Is there a way to get the `href` from the `innertext` and then the `innertext` of the `href`?

I wish that this site had a class on their links as that would of course make this tons easier. I have used these functions with no issues because of the websites actually using classes on their links, but it looks like billboard has decided to make things harder for me!

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: My `parser_class.php` is the one that is located [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `h3` with class `title` you have to select the anchor. so `h3.title a` now from that anchor you will get the `href` and `anchor text`. In order to get the href you can create `SimpleXMLElement` object from the anchor html.

```
 <?php
    include ('parser_class.php');
    $source = file_get_html('http://www.billboard.com/search/site/awards?f[0]=ss_bb_type%3Aarticle');
    foreach ($source->find('h3.title a') as $anchor) {
        $anch = new SimpleXMLElement($anchor);
        echo "Anchor text is : ".$anch;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "href is : ";
        echo $link_href = $anch['href'];
        echo "<hr>";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you sooo much, I feel ridiculously silly that it was such an easy fix that I could not figure out.